# UWP's USB functions cannot communicate with an Android device

Tags: android, uwp, usb

I'm trying to build a UWP app which communicates with an Android device (currently my Samsung Galaxy S5, but could be anything else) and activates Accessory Mode on the device.

So far I have successfully implemented `Windows.Devices.Usb` and the device's VID and PID to locate the device and get its ID when it is connected, but when I use `UsbDevice device = await UsbDevice.FromIdAsync(d.Id);` with the device ID, it just returns null and I cannot communicate with the device.

I have added USB capability in the package.appxmanifest file, and the device manager shows the phone correctly as Samsung Mobile USB Composite Device. Still somehow the UWP app fails to get my Android device from its ID. I don't know how to solve this, as I'm a complete newbie when it comes to both UWP and USB.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you didn't provide any code snippet, not sure if anythings wrong with your code snippet or configuration. Please try to test it with the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CustomUsbDeviceAccess) firstly, for how to test please reference the "Customizing the sample for your device" section of the sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it turns out that UWP USB functions are only for ['miscellaneous' devices using winusb.sys drivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28721091/c-sharp-windows-store-app-returning-null-for-usbdevice), and Android devices do not belong to that category so they can't be used with `Windows.Devices.Usb` functions.